# How can I print the string to center of a receipt

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using Pos for .net.

Below is a vb code, how can I convert to c# to print receipt:

```
   Public Const ESC = Chr(&H1B) & "|"
        Public Const SetBold = ESC & "bC"
        Public Const SetUnderline = ESC & "uC"
        Public Const SetItalic = ESC & "iC"
        Public Const SetCentre = ESC & "cA"
        Public Const SetRight = ESC & "rA"
        Public Const ResetFormatting = ESC & "N"

 Dim msg As String = "This is a test" & vbCrLf & SetBold & SetSize(3) & SetCentre & "it works" & SetSize(1) & " pretty well" & vbCrLf & "OK"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `vbCrLf` with `"\r\n"`

```
Public Const ESC = Chr(&H1B) + "|" ;
        Public Const SetBold = ESC+ "bC";
        Public Const SetUnderline = ESC + "uC";
        Public Const SetItalic = ESC +"iC" ;
        Public Const SetCentre = ESC + "cA" ;
        Public Const SetRight = ESC + "rA" ;
        Public Const ResetFormatting = ESC + "N" ;

 String msg = "This is a test" + "\r\n"+ SetBold + SetSize(3)+ SetCentre + "it works" +SetSize(1) + " pretty well" + "\r\n" + "OK" ;
```

Comment: You will need semicolons too.

Answer (score 0):

IN general, if you need to translate VB to C#, use something a bit more automatic: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ for example.